# Handle exception with clojure

Tags: exception, clojure, apache-pig

On my clojure script I have got a try/catch that should handle exception

```
                datalayer (try (parse-dl line)
                           (catch Exception e []))
```

But when I execute my code i'have got an exception:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value

What should I do to ignore those exceptions

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing the rest of your code. Could you at least post the `parse-dl` function?

Comment: Without seeing additional code, it is not clear what you are asking. The uncaught exception likely does not occur where you think it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is just a guess because I don't know what parse-dl does, though there is a common pattern that causes Exceptions to be thrown outside the try catch where they are expected. If you start with some lazy code in a try catch:

```
user> (def my-data [1 2 3])
#'user/my-data
user> (defn my-work [data]
        (throw (Exception. "hi")))
#'user/my-work
user> (try
        (map my-work my-data)
        (catch Exception e []))
Exception hi  user/my-work (form-init3735135586498578464.clj:1)
```

Because map returns a lazy sequence, the **actual computation occurs when the REPL prints the result**, so the exception is thrown after the try catch block has returned. To fix the lazy-bug, wrap the map in a call to `doall`

```
user> (try
        (doall (map my-work my-data))
        (catch Exception e []))
[]
```

Another related lazy-bug occurs when a lazy sequence is returned from a `with-open` expression so that by the time the computation takes place the file was already closed by the with-open macro.